# regarding the itunes com sdk, is there a way to load files to an application

Tags: windows, sdk, itunes, itunes-sdk

Example - there is a free application called Stanza - when my iDevice is connected, I can load files to the application through iTunes which then makes them accessible in the application after disconnecting.
I would like to enable the automated upload of documents, as an example, using the itunes com interface on Windows but i have been unable to find a way to do it in the sdk documentation.
Any thoughts, hints, or clues are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Open Xcode then select the info.plist of your project 
Add a new entry and write APPLICATION SUPPORT ITUNES FILE SHARING
Autocomplete feature will help you when you begin to write
And set the bool value to YES

Build and Run!!

Now every time you connect your device to iTunes you will be able to upload files to your app and download files from your app

Good luck

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer.  Unfortunately, I'm running windows so I don't think this solution will work.  Again, thank you for the attempt.